In JQ how to safely process optionally null values
I have this JSON:
[
  {
    "alert_timestamp": "2024-10-23T08:49:08Z",
    "odin_timestamp": "2024-10-23T08:50:10Z",
    "alert_url": null,
    "comments": null,
    "owner": null,
    "updated_date": null,
    "clear_timestamp": "2024-10-23T09:27:39Z",
    "outage_duration_in_minutes": 38.52,
    "published_on": "DEFAULT",
    "atr_exec_id": null,
    "atr_status": null
  }
]

And, in the even that some fields, like comments isn't null, I need to strip out newlines and tabs. If it is null, then keep it null
I have tried the following:
map(.comments? |= (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; ""))) |
map(.alert_message? |= (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; "")))

Which results in:
jq: error (at 16.json:338): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string

And I have tried the // alternative operator:
map((.comments // "") |= (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; ""))) |
map((.alert_message // "") |= (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; "")))

yielding:
jq: error (at 16.json:338): Invalid path expression with result ""

There has to be a simple way to handle this without an if else

Since you want to keep the nulls, you could use ? on the RHS:
map(.comments |= ( (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; ""))? // null ))   |
map(.alert_message |= ( (gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; ""))? // null))

And for brevity, you could combine the two calls to gsub:
gsub("(\r\n)|\t"; "")

Note also that (assuming your jq allows if-without-else) you could simply write:
map(if .comments then gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; "") end )


For reference, if you wanted to ensure .comments was always a string, you could use . // "" on the RHS of the assignment operator:
map(.comments |= (. // "" | gsub("\r\n"; "") | gsub("\t"; "")))


I am not a fan of branching in general. Let me try your first 2 suggestions

You can use tostring if you don't mind null values converting to a string ("comments": "null")
jq 'map(.comments|=(tostring|gsub("[\\r\\n\\t]+";" ")))'

